# How do you check for the presence of a string in a text file based on the elements of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have an array containing strings.
I have a text file.
I want to loop through the text file line by line.
And check whether each element of my array is present or not.
   (they must be whole words and not substrings)
I am stuck because my script only checks for the presence of the first array element.
However, I would like it to return results with each array element and a note as to whether this array element is present in the entire file or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/python



with open("/home/all_genera.txt") as file:

    generaA=[]

    for line in file:
        line=line.strip('\n')
        generaA.append(line)


with open("/home/config/config2.cnf") as config_file:
    counter = 0
    for line in config_file:
        line=line.strip('\n')

        for part in line .split():
            if generaA[counter]in part:
                print (generaA[counter], "is -----> PRESENT")
            else:
                continue
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a sequence of words that are in both files. If yes, `set` is your friend:

```
def parse(f):
    return set(word for line in f for word in line.strip().split())

with open("path/to/genera/file") as f:
    source = parse(f)
with open("path/to/conf/file" as f:
    conf = parse(f)

# elements that are common to both sets
common = conf & source
print(common)

# elements that are in `source` but not in `conf`
print(source - conf)

# elements that are in `conf` but not in `source`
print(conf - source)
```

So to answer "I would like it to return results with each array element and a note as to whether this array element is present in the entire file or not", you can use either common elements or the `source - conf` difference to annotate your `source` list:

```
# using common elements
common = conf & source
result = [(word, word in common) for word in source]
print(result)

# using difference
diff = source - conf
result = [(word, word not in diff) for word in source]
```

Both will yeld the same result and since set lookup is O(1) perfs should be similar too, so I suggest the first solution (positive assertions are easier to the brain than negative ones).

You can of course apply further cleaning / normalisation when building the sets, ie if you want case insensitive search:

```
def parse(f):
    return set(word.lower() for line in f for word in line.strip().split())
```

Comment: Hi, I like this idea, but how can I print what isn't common between the source folder and the config file as opposed to what is common?

Comment: So many options in python it sometimes seems bewildering, thanks I will test this out.

Comment: Well, Python has most of the usual features so you can do things in the usual brute force style (nested loops over lists etc). But it also has a lot of nice features and a rich set of builtin types that make life easier when you know they exist and when to use them. Most of the time when you find yourself writing "brute force" style code in Python you should stop and ask yourself "which builtin data type would solve this in a cleaner way". Using the right data type is key to writing good code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding that out more and more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collection import Counter
import re

#first normalize the text (lowercase everything and remove puncuation(anything not alphanumeric)
normalized_text = re.sub("[^a-z0-9 ]","",open("some.txt","rb").read().lower())
# note that this normalization is subject to the rules of the language/alphabet/dialect you are using, and english ascii may not cover it

#counter will collect all the words into a dictionary of [word]:count
words = Counter(normalized_text.split())

# create a new set of all the words in both the text and our word_list_array
set(my_word_list_array).intersection(words.keys())
```

Comment: What if any of the files contains non English words ? There are quite a few other alphabets than ascii you know ?

Comment: sure ... thats why normalized_text is its own thing ... its on the user to specify what is required to normalize text in the alphabet they are interested in

Comment: This is an ideal idea except when I tried this it complained about the fact that bits (or array elements) can't be assessed with regular expressions.

`TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Comment: try `re.sub(b"[^a-z0-9 ]"...` :)

Answer (score -1):

the counter is not increasing because it's outside the `for` loops.

```
with open("/home/all_genera.txt") as myfile: # don't use 'file' as variable, is a reserved word! use myfile instead

    generaA=[]

    for line in myfile: # use .readlines() if you want a list of lines!
        generaA.append(line)

# if you just need to know if string are present in your file, you can use .read():
with open("/home/config/config2.cnf") as config_file:
    mytext = config_file.read()
    for mystring in generaA:
        if mystring in mytext:
            print mystring, "is -----> PRESENT"

# if you want to check if your string in line N is present in your file in the same line, you can go with:
with open("/home/config/config2.cnf") as config_file:
    for N, line in enumerate(config):
        if generaA[N] in line:
            print "{0} is -----> PRESENT in line {1}".format(generaA[N], N)
```

I hope that everything is clear.

This code could be improved in many ways, but i tried to have it as similar as yours so it will be easier to understand

Comment: "you are not reading the file at all." => plain wrong. "use .readlines() if you want a list of lines" => no need, files are iterable. Your code only doubles the memory used to read the file, for no good reason.